# iPhone sending Json Array via POST

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, post

I need to send the following **JSON array** via **POST** to our server:

```
task:{"id":"123","list":"456","done":1,"done_date":1305016383}
```

I tried with the **JSON library**, but I was somehow to stupid to use it. I even tried to build up the POST-String by myself, but also failed:

```
NSString *post = @"task='{id:123,list:456,done:1,done_date:1305016383}'";

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData    
                                            timeoutInterval:30];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
....
```

Can you please help me? The json’ed POST string would be even enough for me :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON array format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055475/json-array-format)

Answer (score 1):

So this may or may not be the question you are asking, but your JSON string is not formed correctly. An array of "task" in JSON format would look like this:

```
NSString *post = @"{"task":[{"id":"123","list":"456","done":1,"done_date":1305016383}]}";
```

I was just wresting with a similar situation posting to a PHP server and I couldn't find any questions about it online, but this is what I would've had to do if I were posting the same data:

```
NSString *post = @"task[0][id]=123&task[0][list]=456&task[0][done]=1&task[0][done_date]=1305016383&";

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData    
                                        timeoutInterval:30];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
...
```

Good luck!

Comment: work like a charm and solve our problem which took us few hours

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle It:

```
-(void)imageFactory:(NSDictionary*)postJSON
{
    // Convert the JSON string to Data to be sent.
    NSData* postData = [[postJSON JSONRepresentation] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[URLManager imageFactory]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    // IMPORTANT MAKE SURE YOU ADD THIS LINE SO THE SERVER KNOWS WHAT ITS GETTING
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    // Add some nice handlers so you know what you got from the server
    NSURLResponse* response;
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse;
    NSError* error;
    NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString* stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
    int statuscode = [httpResponse statusCode];

    if (statuscode == 200)
    {
        log4Debug(@"ImageFactory Response Successful, Retrieving image");
        // Handle the response here if needed
    }
    else
    {
        log4Error(@"ImageFactory Response Failed: %@", stringResponse);
        // Show some form of alert here if needed
    }
    // release all objects saved to memory
    [request release];
    request = nil;
    [stringResponse release];
    stringResponse = nil;
}
```

My json is a string that looks like this
{"user":1337,"title":"Some title","itemKeys":[1,1,1,1,1]}

Comment: ``No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'JSONRepresentation'`` have you seen this error?

Comment: hey, were you able to figure out that error? it's doing the same thing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is not with the methods, but with the string you're trying to post. Try this one:

```
NSString *post = @"\"task\":{\"id\":\"123\",\"list\":\"456\",\"done\":1,\"done_date\":1305016383}";
```

In other words: experiment with the quotation marks.

What JSON library are you using?

Comment: I am using this JSON library: http://stig.github.com/json-framework  your example worked after I changed the start of your string to task={\"id\":

Comment: JSON framework is a well known library. Though I use JSONkit, I believe JSON framework does the job correctly and returns well-formed strings. Thus the problem is either on the server side or in the objects which you pass to the JSON framework.